# Retrieve the length of variable argument list

Tags: lua

```
function countargs(...)
  return #arg
end

> countargs(1, 2, 3)
0
```

In this case, countargs returns 0 and not 3. How to retrieve the length of the variable argument list?

I tested against Lua 5.3 and 5.4 on Windows.

Comment: `arg` exists only in Lua 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of elements in `...` can be computed via `select("#", ...)`. Note that this will include any embedded `nil` elements, unlike syntaxes like `#{...}`.

However, you generally don't need the length directly; what you really need is a table containing the elements in question. To build this, call `table.pack(...)`. This will return a table containing all of the `...` elements, and the length will be at the key `"n"`, which allows you to iterate over even the embedded `nil` elements of `...`.

Answer (score 1):

```lua
function countargs(...)
  local arg = {...}
  return #arg
end
```

or

```lua
function countargs(...)
  return #{...}
end
```